# GRUB: escape acpi_osi="Windows 2015" in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX

Tags: grub2, kernel-parameters

How do I escape the string:

```
acpi_osi="Windows 2015"
```

To keep the space and quotes in GRUB's `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`?

[Alternate search term: `acpi_os_name=`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct quoting / escaping format to use is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\" ... "
```

Then `/proc/cmdline` will contain:

`"acpi_osi=Windows 2015"`